# How many possible ways to cross the bridges at once, if we know the problem has solution?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

[Source: Diagram from Euler’s 1736 paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN5tr.png)

In the above diagram,
How many possible ways to cross the bridges at once, if we know the problem has solution?

Comment: You have the solution in wikipedia

Comment: If the graph is undirected, you're in for a treat -- it is [#P-complete.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Counting_Eulerian_circuits)

Comment: @igael I'm not asking, Is there is any possible path or not. This problem has solution i know! But, I'm asking "How many"?

Comment: @DamodarRajbhandari And Wikipedia has a section "Counting Eulerian circuits." Follow the link above.

Comment: I saw the link just now!Thanks @ClementC. But, what if for a Eulerian path? In my question , I haven't mentioned it whether it is the number of Eulerian path or Eulerian circuit. I'm saying, lets both.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this is the same. If you have Eulerian paths that are not circuits,  then exactly two vertices have odd degree, and all such paths start at one and end at the other. So there is an easy reduction between the two variants.

Comment: Sir @ClementC. Would you please solve it how?